# Overlay a Carousel on top of Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hidden carousel of images that only appears when a user clicks a image. My problem right now is that drawing the carousel pushes the table down, how can I overlay the carousel on top of the existing table? Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        table {border: none;}

    </style>

    <script>
        function toggleOverlay() {
            var div = document.getElementById('overlay');
            if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
                div.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }
        };

    </script>

    <body>
        <h1 align="center">TYPE OF CLOTHING </h1>
        <h2 align="left"> OLD NAVY </h2>

        <button  style="float: right;" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1)"> Back </button>

        <div>
            <!-- Carousel Code -->
            <div id="overlay" style="display: none;">

                <button type="button" onclick="toggleOverlay()"> X </button>

                <div class="container">
                  <br>
                  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                      <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Chania</h3>
                          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Chania</h3>
                          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Flowers</h3>
                          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Flowers</h3>
                          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <table align="center" border="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="margin: 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
                <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to describe exactly what you mean by overlay? Your carousel pushes the table down as expected. Do you want it to overlay and prevent the user from seeing the top part of your table? could you draw what you mean?

Comment: By overlay I mean I want the the carousel to sit on top of the of table in the center of the page, dim the color of the table as well

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each section in a DIV, and make the carousel's wrapping div `position:absolute` (you can also add `top:100px` to move it down, if required, and perhaps `width:999px` or what have you)

`position:absolute` will remove the DIV from the HTML "flow" and allow you to position it anywhere you want ***relative to its parent DIV*** (in this case, the document `body`).

Note: If you wish to place an absolutely-positioned DIV inside another DIV, that (parent) div must be either `position:absolute` itself, or else `position:relative` *(very similar to the default, `position:static`, except that it will permit absolutely positioned elements inside it)*

```js
function toggleOverlay() {
  var div = document.getElementById('overlay');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
table {border: none;}

#carouselDIV{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h1 align="center">TYPE OF CLOTHING </h1>
<h2 align="left"> OLD NAVY </h2>

<button  style="float: right;" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1)"> Back </button>

<div id="carouselDIV">
  <!-- Carousel Code -->
  <div id="overlay" style="display: none;">

    <button type="button" onclick="toggleOverlay()"> X </button>

    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Chania</h3>
              <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Chania</h3>
              <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Flowers</h3>
              <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Flowers</h3>
              <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tableDIV">
  <table align="center" border="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="margin: 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
      <td align="center" onclick="toggleOverlay()"><img src="http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201412/HiAppHere_com_com.studio8apps.instasizenocrop.png" alt="description here" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```